# How to redirect to external service page on post request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, redirect, post

I am posting some information to some external service, upon which it process the post params and should show its own page with the parameters I have sent.

i.e It should be redirected to their site upon post request from my side.

Here's what I am doing:
I am using HTTParty to post the data to the their URL and storing the response in response object and using render :html to render to response.

I am getting a their html in response object.

here's the code:

```
     example_url = 'https://www.example.com/service.aspx'
  post_params = build_params # builds params for post request
  response = HTTParty.post(cams_url_two,
                body: URI.encode_www_form(post_params),
                headers: { 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
                verify: false)
  @result[:url] = response.body
```

And in controller I am using render

```
render html: result[:url].html_safe
```

However, what is happening here is the response returns html which is rendered on my own application i.e localhost, it is also trying to search its assets in my app.

What is expected here is upon hitting a post request it should redirect to their site.

Any advice or help on how do I do achieve this?

Thank You!

Comment: Are you trying to redirect the page to response `url`?

Comment: @hgsongra yes that is what I want to do. but instead of getting a response url, I am receiving a entire response page in my response object.

Comment: replace your last line in above code block with this code `redirect_to response.body` I am assuming that your `response.body` returning `url`

Comment: @hgsongra just tried it and response is not returning url but the entire html page of the eternal service in string format. when checked the class of the response it is 'HTTParty::Response' just thought it might be of some use.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
redirect_to @result[:url].html_safe
```

If you want the user to be redirected, then use `redirect_to`. If you want to render a page, then use `render html:...`

Comment: unfortunately, that's not what I want here is upon hitting a post request I should be directly redirected to the response page of the external service.
I tried redirect before but no luck with it.